# Segregate Products based on shipping <SQL>

Tags: postgresql

I have 10 different products (A,B,C),..,J)have multiple purchase dates (by various customers) and delivery dates. I want to see which products have the date difference of less than 5 days. If the date difference is less than 5 days, which products have customer rating less more than 3.If the above criteria is satisfied I want to fetch those products that has the minimum date difference from the queue along with the "Important_date".If there are same minimum date difference for a particular product then I would like to select the top one among the same product in recent times and mark the purchase date as the "Important_date".

The columns in the table are: Product,Purchasedate,deliverydate,date_difference,customer_rating.

I am trying to use case statements to solve the problem in PostgreSQL.
I am looking for an output which will give me all the columns of the table along with "Important_date."

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. It is also advisable to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..
Since *I have three different products. These 10 different products (A,B,C),..,J)* 
is already contradictory it's good idea to edit your questions so it attracts more possible answers..